# Prime number lemma proof needed

Tags: number-theory

I would like to prove that the maximum divisor of a number $n$ (excluding $n$ itself), is always divisible by the minimum prime factor of $n$ if and only if $n$ itself is divisible by the square of it's minimum prime factor.

Comment: And what have you done towards accomplishing this?  Can you prove it in one direction?

Comment: Let $k<n $ be the maximum proper divisor of $n$. Then $kr=n$ for some $r>1$. Then - what can you say about $r$?

Comment: I intuitively believe it to be true and if a proof exists then I would prefer to see another more experienced person's proof rather than muck about with my own. In the meantime I  will try on my own, but why would a waste times asking everyone else?

Comment: $r$ would have to be the minimum proper divisor of $n$

Comment: Yes (provided $n$ is not prime) - can you prove that $r$ must be prime?

Comment: Well it needs to be square free

Comment: but no not entirely clear yet as to how to show it must be prime

Comment: If it's not prime, then it factors and any of its factors pairs with a larger divisor of $n$ than $k$...

Comment: sorry what do you mean by pair?

Comment: ... multiplies together with the divisor to get $n$...

Comment: Hint : If $p$ is the smallest prime factor of $n$, then the maximum divisor of $n$ excluding $n$ itself is $\frac{n}{p}$

Comment: That's true this could be a lot easier than I thought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k$ be the maximum divisor of $n$.  Then $n=kr$, where $r$ is the minimum prime factor.  Now $r\mid k\iff k=sr$ for some $s \iff n=sr^2\iff r^2\mid n$

Answer (score 2):

$n=p^2r$ where $p$ is the smallest factor of $n$ iff the largest divisor of $n$ is $n/p=pr$.